# Prevent the y-axis in a d3 line graph from going below 0 on drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have a line d3 line graph (can be viewed here - [the graph](http://talonsoftwares.com/d3Test/)). The graph allows zooming only on the y axis. By default it allows dragging. I want to stop people from being able to drag below 0 on the y-axis. I read somewhere that there no need writing a new function for dragging because zooming handles that. I therefore tried to implement the logic on my function (redraw) that is called when you zoom but have not been able to figure out how I can prevent people from dragging below 0 on the y axis. Below is the code for the redraw function

```
function redraw() {  

    if (y.domain()[0] < 0) {
            y.domain()[0] = 0;
            vis.selectAll("[ty='line']").attr('d', line); 
            vis.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);               
            return;

    } else {
        vis.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
        vis.selectAll("[ty='line']").attr('d', line);
    }        
}
```

Comment: See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/garrilla/11280861).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks a lot for this. It is somewhat buggy still but works like 90% of the time

Comment: Hmm, the example works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link to how to solve the issue was posted in the comments by Lars Kotthoff